# QuestPDF does not save the PDF and does not open on a new tab

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, pdf

Iam using QuestPDF in asp.net core web application.
PDF is looking good and has everything it should.
The issue is it is not displaying in the browser but rather in acrobat reader or anything similar when I use .GeneratePdfAndShow()
When I use .GeneratePdf() It does not show at all
I need the document to be showed to the user preferably in a new tab as a PDF so they can print and move on inside the application

The issue is I cannot call the Print() function from JS if I could I would just say on the success window.open _blank
But I need to call the Print() function from another action point Iam doing it like so:

```
  if (newKanbanItems.Any())
 {
     List<Object> KanbanOBJS = new List<Object>();
     foreach (var item in newKanbanItems) 
     {
         int position = _db.ListContentCST.FirstOrDefault(x => x.LCCST_Id == item.KL_ListContentId).LCCST_Position;
         Object KanbanOBJ = new
         {
             LCCST_Position = position,
             PagodaPlace = item.KL_PagodaPlace,
             Leadset = item.KL_Material,
             QtyOfBundles = item.KL_QtyOfBundles
         };
         KanbanOBJS.Add(KanbanOBJ);
     }
     Print(area, userCST, name, KanbanOBJS);
 }
```

I need to call it from the Backend because I can than go thru a loop to get all of the objects I need to print:

```
 // Inserting the Table right after the row
 column.Item()
 .PaddingTop(3)
 .Table(table =>
 {
     table.ColumnsDefinition(columns =>
     {
         columns.RelativeColumn();
         columns.RelativeColumn();
         columns.RelativeColumn();
         columns.RelativeColumn();
         columns.RelativeColumn();
     });
     table.Header(header =>
     {
         header.Cell()
         .Border(6, unit: Unit.Mil)
         .AlignCenter()
         .AlignMiddle()
         .Text("LCCST_Position");
         header.Cell()
         .Border(6, unit: Unit.Mil)
         .AlignCenter()
         .AlignMiddle()
         .Text("Pagoda Place");
         header.Cell()
         .Border(6, unit: Unit.Mil)
         .AlignCenter()
         .AlignMiddle()
         .Text("Leadset");
         header.Cell()
         .Border(6, unit: Unit.Mil)
         .AlignCenter()
         .AlignMiddle()
         .Text("Quantity of Bundles");
         header.Cell()
         .Border(6, unit: Unit.Mil)
         .AlignCenter()
         .AlignMiddle()
         .Text("Commisioned?");
     });
     foreach (var item in KanbanOBJ)
     {
         dynamic obj = item;
         table.Cell()
         .AlignCenter()
         .AlignMiddle()
         .Text($"{obj.LCCST_Position}");
         table.Cell()
         .AlignCenter()
         .AlignMiddle()
         .Text($"{obj.PagodaPlace}");
         table.Cell()
         .AlignCenter()
         .AlignMiddle()
         .Text($"{obj.Leadset}");
         table.Cell()
         .AlignCenter()
         .AlignMiddle()
         .Text($"{obj.QtyOfBundles}");
         table.Cell()
         .AlignCenter()
         .AlignMiddle()
         .Text("");
     }

 });
```

Does anyone have any workaround ?

I tried every QuestPDF
.Generate() methods
I tried to ask ChatGPT about the issue and checked the QuestPDF documentation haven't found anything helpful

The file cannot be saved locally it needs to be opened in the browser

Comment: _I tried to ask ChatGPT check the QuestPDF documentation_: Since that didn't work, are you asking us to _check the QuestPDF documentation_? Have you checked the _QuestPDF documentation_ without using any search engines or AI?

Comment: My bad I have asked chatGPT about how can I use the QestPDF to open the pdf in a new browser Tab, and also checked the QuestPDF documentation @user246821

Comment: @KJ Unfortunately no, I need to be able to work explicitly inside the browser since the end user will be working with scanner that can access the browser but I cannot save files in the scanner directly

Comment: The issue is not that human needs to execute the print.
The issue was that the PDF was showing in acrobat or whatever application I have set as default to open PDFs. I needed to make sure it is open directly in the browser since the scanners that will be used in production does not have windows and the default QuestPDF tries to execute the defaultWindows app to open the PDF this way they cannot even see nor print the PDF since scanners have only access to the browser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this issue via a few steps esentially im using blob to display the PDF in the frontend and im saving my PDF to base64String

## Steps

### fetching my data back to the fronted:

```
if (newKanbanItems.Any())
{
    List<KanbanItem> KanbanOBJS = new List<KanbanItem>();
    foreach (var item in newKanbanItems)
    {
        int position = _db.ListContentCST.FirstOrDefault(x => x.LCCST_Id == item.KL_ListContentId).LCCST_Position;
        KanbanItem KanbanOBJ = new()
        {
            LCCST_Position = position,
            PagodaPlace = item.KL_PagodaPlace,
            Leadset = item.KL_Material,
            QtyOfBundles = item.KL_QtyOfBundles
        };
        KanbanOBJS.Add(KanbanOBJ);
    }
    return new JsonResult(new { success = true, message = listSaved, listId = name, KanbanOBJ = KanbanOBJS });
```

### Than I call a frontend function in my success that executes the print:

```
 success: function (result) {
     if (result.success) {
         displaySuccessMessage(result.message, "");
         listCSTTable.ajax.reload();

         generateAndOpenPdf(result.listId, result.KanbanOBJ);
         
     }
     else {
         displayErrorMessage(result.message, "");
         listCSTTable.ajax.reload();
     }
 }
```

### The PrintCall:

```
function generateAndOpenPdf(listId, KanbanOBJ) {
    var area = "@area";
    var userCST = "@CSTUser";
    var printUrl = "@Url.Action("Print", "ScannerCST")";

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: printUrl,
        data: JSON.stringify({ Area: area, User: userCST, ListId: listId, KanbanOBJ: KanbanOBJ }),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (result) {
            if (result.success && result.pdfBase64) {
                var pdfData = atob(result.pdfBase64);
                var arrayBuffer = new Uint8Array(pdfData.length);
                for (var i = 0; i < pdfData.length; i++) {
                    arrayBuffer[i] = pdfData.charCodeAt(i);
                }
                var blob = new Blob([arrayBuffer], { type: "application/pdf" });
                var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                window.open(url, '_blank');
            } else {
                console.error("PDF generation failed or no base64 string provided.");
            }
        },
       
    });
}
```

### And finally I have changed the print to Generate the pdf into base64String and encode it in a success in the frontend:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Print([FromBody] PrintKanban model)

{
    QuestPDF.Settings.License = LicenseType.Community;
    var stream = new MemoryStream();
    Document.Create(document =>
    {
        //Document creation here
    }).GeneratePdf(stream);
    stream.Position = 0;
    var bytes = stream.ToArray();
    var base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);

    return Json(new { success = true, pdfBase64 = base64String });
}
```